# Is it possible to conditionally "use bigint" with Perl?

Tags: perl, conditional-statements, biginteger

I know I can conditionally use a module in Perl but what about the "pragmas"? My tests have shown that `use bigint` can be much slower than normal math in Perl and I only need it to handle 64-bit integers so I only want to use it when Perl wasn't built with 64-bit integer support, which I also know how to check for using the `Config` module.

I tried various things with `eval` and `BEGIN` blocks but couldn't work out a way to conditionally use bigint. I know I can use `Math::BigInt` but then I can't use a single codepath for both the bigint and 64-bit cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This actually works just fine:

```
use Config;
BEGIN {
  if (! $Config{use64bitint}) {
    require bigint;
    bigint->import;
  }
}
```

The interaction between different compile-times is complicated (maybe I'll come back and try to explain it later) but suffice it to say that since there's no string eval here, the flag that bigint sets will persist through the rest of the file or block that you put that BEGIN block inside.

Comment: It's crazy but I didn't try this because I assumed `bigint` was fundamentally different to modules like `Math::BigInt`! Specifically I didn't think I could use it with `->import`. Thanks for proving me wrong!

Comment: @hippietrail pragmas do weird things in their import routines -- but they still have import routines :)

Answer (score 13):

You can take hobbs' answer and stick it in a module.

```
package int64;

use Config;

sub import {
    if (! $Config{use64bitint}) {
        require bigint;
        bigint->import;
    }
}

1;
```

Then `use int64` will do what you mean.  Even though bigint is lexical, calling it inside another import routine will make it pass along its magic.

Comment: don't forget to return 1 at the end of the module!

Comment: This is a great and elegant solution but I'm going to accept hobbs's answer as canonical since it was first and the essence is the same.

Answer (score 12):

Use the [if](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if) module. It uses `goto` to hide its own stack frame, so it's as if the pragma was called directly.

The solutions given previously may work for `bigint` and most pragmas, but they will fail for `import` functions that use `caller`.

Comment: `if` is a good, general solution to the problem.  (to deal with imports, you can `goto module->can('import')`)